# Regex matching some and not matchin other combinations of characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match strings containing letters `A`, `B` or `C` (1), with the exception if a letter is directly preceded by a caret (e.g., `A^`) (2). There are no consecutive carets, but letters and numbers can come with stretches of all lengths and combinations. Ideally regex would be without lookaheads, as I'd like to use in `Awk` script.

```
43AA34C563B3545  :  no match
43A34C563^BC3545 :  no match
4334563^B3545    :  match (the only letter is after the caret)
3345664345^CCC0  :  no match
3345             :  match (no letters)
```

I can do #1 relatively easily with `^[^ABC]+$` but when I try to add to expand it e.g.,
`^[^ABC]+$|^[0-9]*\^D+[0-9]+$` it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matches are made of either a carat then [ABC] *or* a digit:

```
^((\^[ABC])|\d)+$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/V75OLxrYEZ9UWL).

Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` if your regex flavour doe  add by support `\d` (eg awk or sed).

Comment: Nice. Helped me double, as with a minor modification: '^((\^[ABC]+)|\d)+$' it excludes strings with letter stretches following the caret, which is another thing I needed! Thanks!

Comment: However...  \  escape in `gawk/awk 5.1.0` gives `warning: regexp escape sequence '\d' is not a known regexp operator`

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk if your tool doesn’t support `\d` use `[0-9]` instead...

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk there's no ```\d``` in gawk. Use char class: ```[[:digit:]]```.
Also I don't how you're using this regex, but you need to use a **static** regex when possible - surrounded with /-s, not "-s: ```awk '/^((\^[ABC])|[[:digit:]])+$/' myFile```

Comment: @vgersh99 surely `[0-9]` is easier and simpler than `[[:digit:]]`

Answer (score 2):

You might use a pattern to match digits and repeat matching `^` followed by one of `[ABC]` and digits

```
^[0-9]+(\^[ABC][0-9]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WVHLP/1)

```
awk '/^[0-9]+(\^[ABC][0-9]+)*$/ {
  print $0
}

' file
```

Output

```
4334563^B3545
3345
```

Or a version that would also match only `^B` or only digits:

```
^([0-9]*(\^[ABC][0-9]*)+|[0-9]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BHonyt/1)